# Put percent labels next to legend instead of in the slice

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Let me preface this by saying Pie Charts were not my choice, it is a facet of a report that was requested by a supervisor. 
I have a series of pie charts created from the following code:

```
perpie <- Full_Mod_good %>%
  split(.$ServiceSite) %>%
  imap(function(data, site) {
    data %>%
    group_by(ServiceSite, InitialType) %>%
    summarise(count = n()) %>%
    mutate(share = round(count / sum(count), digits = 2)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = "", y = share, fill = InitialType)) +
    geom_col(width = 1) +
    geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(share)), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
    coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0, direction = 1)+
    ggtitle(site)+
    ylab("Percentage of Healed Wounds")+
    xlab("")+
    theme_minimal()+
    theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.grid  = element_blank())+
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
        })
perpie
```

with about 50 plots resembling this:
[image]

I would like to add the percentages to the labels in legend but am unsure of how to do this. I have tried spreading the labels out around the perimeter of the graph but, due to the large number of initial types, it sometimes becomes challenging to distinguish between similar shades of a color. Adding the percentages to the legend would eliminate this.

Sample Data

```
ServiceSite.x InitialType
2   Dermatitis
2   Diabetic
2   Pressure Injury
2   Pressure Injury
3   Pressure Injury
3   Other
3   Laceration
3   Other
4   Pressure Injury
4   MASD
4   Blister (Non-Pressure)
4   Skin Tear
4   Pressure Injury
5   Skin Tear
5   Other
5   Contusion
5   Skin Tear
5   Surgical(Non-Healing)
5   Pressure Injury
6   Pressure Injury
1   Pressure Injury
6   Pressure Injury
6   MASD
1   Surgical(Non-Healing)
1   Pressure Injury
1   Skin Tear
1   Contusion
```

Comment: Two thought on pie charts:  [one](https://blog.funnel.io/why-we-dont-use-pie-charts-and-some-tips-on-better-data-visualizations) and [two](https://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/save_the_pies_for_dessert.pdf)

Comment: @DanY As I stated, this was not something I had any say in.

Comment: This is more a style answer, I agree that putting the percentages next to the labels is a good idea, which makes the pie chart completely worthless.  I suggest creating a table to present your data and forget pie charts even exist.  Don't take my word, read Ed Tufte's work.

Comment: Again, @Dave2e , it was requested of me and was not my preferred method.

Answer (score 2):

My condolences on being forced into a pie chart. You can just add a column with labels that include percentages, and then use that as your fill variable. Here's an example with one of the subsets of the data (I chose `ServiceSite.x == 5` because this had a fair number of observations to work with.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_label <- df %>%
  filter(ServiceSite.x == 5) %>%
  count(InitialType) %>%
  mutate(share = round(n / sum(n), digits = 2)) %>%
  mutate(label = scales::percent(share), labeled_type = sprintf("%s (%s)", InitialType, label))

df_label
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   InitialType               n share label labeled_type               
#>   <chr>                 <int> <dbl> <chr> <chr>                      
#> 1 Contusion                 1  0.17 17%   Contusion (17%)            
#> 2 Other                     1  0.17 17%   Other (17%)                
#> 3 Pressure                  1  0.17 17%   Pressure (17%)             
#> 4 Skin                      2  0.33 33%   Skin (33%)                 
#> 5 Surgical(Non-Healing)     1  0.17 17%   Surgical(Non-Healing) (17%)

ggplot(df_label, aes(x = 1, y = n, fill = labeled_type)) +
  geom_col(width = 1) +
  geom_text(aes(label = label), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Created on 2018-07-25 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: great expression, "my condolences on being forced into a pie chart".. Hahaha.