# Add counts to legend labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, purrr

I am trying to add the counts/percentages to legend labels of a pie chart. Pie charts are terrible, I know, but that's not the point of this post. I would like to paste the values of "Count" to the "Wound.Type" label on the legend but can't figure out how to access the Counts for each iteration of the following code. The goal would be something along the lines of "Laceration 5" or whatever the count is. I have tried ".~Count" and ".~Wound.Type", ".$Count" and ".$Wound.Type" but I don't understand how to access the specific values I'd like.

```
p1 <- DF %>% 
  split(.$ServiceSite) %>%
  imap(function(data, site) {
    data %>%
  group_by(ServiceSite, Wound.Type) %>%
  summarise(Count = n()) %>%
   mutate(share = round(Count / sum(Count), digits = 2)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = "", y = Count, fill = Wound.Type)) +
    geom_col(width = 1) +
    scale_fill_discrete(labels = paste(.$Wound.Type, .$Count))+
    facet_grid(facets = .~ServiceSite, labeller = label_value)+
    geom_text(aes(label = Count, y = ), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
    coord_polar(theta = "y")+
    labs(caption = "Visits from 1/1/18-6/30/18")+
    ggtitle("Count of Unique Wound Occurrences")+
    theme(plot.caption = element_text(size= 8, hjust = .5))+
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
    theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
    ylab("")+
    xlab("")+
    theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.grid  = element_blank())
  })
p1
```

Current output:
[image]

data:

```
ServiceSite.x InitialType

2   Dermatitis
2   Diabetic
2   Pressure Injury
2   Pressure Injury
3   Pressure Injury
3   Other
3   Laceration
3   Other
4   Pressure Injury
4   MASD
4   Blister (Non-Pressure)
4   Skin Tear
4   Pressure Injury
5   Skin Tear
5   Other
5   Contusion
5   Skin Tear
5   Surgical(Non-Healing)
5   Pressure Injury
6   Pressure Injury
1   Pressure Injury
6   Pressure Injury
6   MASD
1   Surgical(Non-Healing)
1   Pressure Injury
1   Skin Tear
1   Contusion
```

Comment: How is this different from your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51524641/5325862) a few days ago? My answer there put percentage labels in the legend. If the only difference is using counts instead of percentages, that should just be a minor edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you can use your function arguments for this.  Since the `data` argument refers to the dataset, you can refer to variables in the original dataset directly.  In your example that would be `data$Wound.Type`.

However, you add the `Count` variable dynamically within the function so this isn't in the dataset you pass to the `data` argument.  Instead of passing the dataset directly to `ggplot()` you can make a new object within your function.  This will allow you to refer to variables in this "mutated" dataset.

Here is an example, where I make a new dataset called `dat2` that is used within `ggplot()` and can be used for the `fill` names.

The key changes to the function are making a new object within the function:

```
dat2 = data %>%
            group_by(ServiceSite, Wound.Type) %>%
            summarise(Count = n()) %>%
            mutate(share = round(Count / sum(Count), digits = 2))
```

And using this object for the `fill` labels:

```
scale_fill_discrete(labels = paste(dat2$Wound.Type, dat2$Count))
```

The changes along with the rest of your:

```
DF %>% 
     split(.$ServiceSite) %>%
     imap(function(data, site) {
          dat2 = data %>%
               group_by(ServiceSite, Wound.Type) %>%
               summarise(Count = n()) %>%
               mutate(share = round(Count / sum(Count), digits = 2)) 
          ggplot(dat2, aes(x = "", y = Count, fill = Wound.Type)) +
               geom_col(width = 1) +
               scale_fill_discrete(labels = paste(dat2$Wound.Type, dat2$Count))+
               facet_grid(facets = .~ServiceSite, labeller = label_value)+
               geom_text(aes(label = Count, y = ), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
               coord_polar(theta = "y")+
               labs(caption = "Visits from 1/1/18-6/30/18")+
               ggtitle("Count of Unique Wound Occurrences")+
               theme(plot.caption = element_text(size= 8, hjust = .5))+
               theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
               theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
               ylab("")+
               xlab("")+
               theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
                     axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                     panel.grid  = element_blank())
     })
```