# Adding custom legend in volcano plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to do a volcano plot of a dataset from RNA-seq. I want to add a custom legend with the values of the down regulated, up regulated and no regulated, but I really don't know how I can do that and I can't find a way to do that in Google (maybe my problem it's my inexperience in R).

This is my code of the plot until now:

```
ggplot(df_toxins, aes(x = logFC, y = -log10(FDR))) +
      geom_point(data = subset(df_toxins, logFC > -1 & logFC < 1), 
                 color = "black", alpha = 0.6, size = 1.5) + 
      geom_point(data = subset(df_toxins, logFC < -1), 
                 color = "red", alpha = 0.5, size = 2.5) + 
      geom_point(data = subset(df_toxins, logFC > 1), 
                 color = "blue", alpha = 0.5, size = 2.5) +
      geom_vline(xintercept = c(-1, 1), linetype = "dashed") + 
      geom_hline(yintercept = 0) + 
      theme_linedraw() + 
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 22)) + 
      ggtitle("Toxins")
```

Comment: The simplest way to get a legend out of ggplot2 is to make a variable that holds your categories and map that to aesthetics like color and size. e.g., `df_toxins$category = case_when(logFC > -1 & logFC < 1 ~ "Down Regulated", ....`  and then `aes([what you have], color = category, size = category)`

Comment: Thank you Jon Spring. I had success in add a legend to my plot, but I want to show the counts of down, up and no regulated in the legend too. Can you help me?

Comment: Perhaps this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51616221/add-counts-to-legend-labels